# Update every row with a function's return value in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, cursor, sql-update

I have a cursor and a for to update a table's every row, using a function to get the new value. The table can contain thousands of rows. The function returns a simple string and it is already used in a lot of existing programs, so changing it is not an option.

```
var_item VARCHAR2(20);
CURSOR cursor IS
    SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table1;

BEGIN
OPEN cursor;
LOOP
FETCH cursor INTO var_item;
EXIT WHEN cursor%NOTFOUND;
    UPDATE table1 SET status = (SELECT check_status(var_item) FROM dual) WHERE column1 = var_item;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor;
END;
```

My question is, is there a faster way to do this? I don't like to use cursor because they are very slow. Is there a way to use a simple update for this kind of job? Or to speed up cursors?
I saw a lot of stuff about BULK COLLECT and SELECT FOR UPDATE but I don't really understand these things to tell the truth.
Can someone help me how to do it efficiently, without using too much database performance?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE table1 SET status = check_status(item) WHERE item in (SELECT column1 FROM table1)

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped the WHERE clause, could you please check it again?

Comment: Ah I got it.
Thanks for the tip, if you post an answer, I will gladly accept is.
UPDATE table1 SET status = check_status(column1)

Comment: No thanks at all, you are welcome :)

Comment: In Oracle, always follow this rule: DO EVERYTHING in SQL. If You can't do it in SQL, do it in PLSQL. If you can't do it in PlSql, do it in external code (C#, Java, C++, C). If you can't do it in external code, then you're doing something wrong.